# Group_by() isn't grouping as I would expect

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to summarise some rainfall data using the `bomrang` package and `tidyverse.` I have tried to use `dplyr::group_by(year)` to then use `summarise` and `mean` to calculate the yearly average rainfall. But instead of getting a different yearly average, I get the same average throughout the data frame.

```r
# load the libraries
library(bomrang)
library(tidyverse)

# get the data
perth <- get_historical(009225, "rain")

# group by year and calculate average rainfall per year
perth %>% 
  select(station_number, year:day, rainfall) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(yearly_avg = mean(rainfall, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I would expect a `yearly_avg` value for each of the 26 years of the data so, for example, the 1993 `yearly_avg` should be 2.032013 and 1994 would be 2.026849 etc.

Instead, I am getting just a single value of 2.002883. I have tried using `mutate` and `as.factor` on year to see if that changes the outcome but it didn't.

Comment: Hi, can you post the result of `dput(head(perth))` inside your question.
This way we now what your data looks like.

Comment: It looks like a `data.table` with "`bomrang_tbl`" class. Anyhow `perth %>% as.data.frame() %>%  ...` works fine for me.

Comment: Interestingly the vignette specifically says "Some returned objects have been classed as bomrang_tbl which allow dispatch for dplyr methods, e.g. mutate, filter, select, arrange, slice, rename, and group_by while preserving the header information" so the intention was that it would work. You may want to log it as an issue https://github.com/ropensci/bomrang/issues

Comment: FYI I found a separate but relevant issue when using `bomrang` today so I have logged an issue on their GitHub https://github.com/ropensci/bomrang/issues/105 with both problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is always useful to see if `group_by` had an intended effect. In your pipes, you can go

```
perth %>% 
    select(station_number, year:day, rainfall) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(year) %>% 
    class()
```

And the results is

```
"bomrang_tbl" "data.frame"
```

So it wasn't a grouped tibble, which is usually achieved by `dplyr::group_by`. Not that the `group_by` that was called wasn't a `dplyr` function. So I do not know very well this `bomrang` package (Australian Government Bureau of Meteorology) but it seems to create it's own class, which then overrides the `tidyverse` grouping.

So you kick out that class:

```
perth %>% 
    select(station_number, year:day, rainfall) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    class()
```

Then you get

```
"grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

So ultimately, the following will yield the year-by-year averages:

```
perth %>% 
  select(station_number, year:day, rainfall) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(yearly_avg = mean(rainfall, na.rm = TRUE))
```

You were on the right track. Sometimes packages clash and weird things happen. Always check grouping status, and if necessary use `ungroup`.